# How to access value from other columns from jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
 "aoColumns": [

                        { "data": "STR_CODIGO" },
                        { "data": "STR_TRAYECTORIA", "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "NUM_NOPAVIMENTADO", "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "NUM_PAVIMENTADO", "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "NUM_TOTAL", "orderable": false },
                        {
                            "targets": 5, "data": "STR_NUMREGISTRO", "render": function (data) {
                                var trow = '';
                                var link = '@Html.ActionLink("ver","FichaTecnica", "Busqueda1", new { numregistro = "NUMERO" }, new { target = "_blank" })';
                                var imagen = "";
                                link = link.replace('ver', imagen);
                                trow = link.replace('NUMERO', data);
                                return trow;
                            }, "orderable": false
                        },
                            {
                                "targets": 6, "data": "STR_MAPA", "render": function (data) {
                                    var link = '';
                                    link = '';
                                    link = link + "" + "";
                                    return link;

                                }, "orderable": false
                            }

                    ]
               });
                    };
```

Comment: Could you be more precise in your question ? What did you try, what is the context ?

Comment: i am trying in data column createa a function to read other column value for aplying  a conditional instruction. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#function) allows you to define a function to be used to render content of a cell.

Function receives four arguments, third argument `row` contains data for the whole row. Please note, that `row` will have the same structure (array or object) as original data.

For example:

```
{
    "targets": 6,
    "data": "STR_MAPA",
    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
       if(type === 'display){
          data = row['STR_NUMREGISTRO']; 
       }

       return data;
    }
},
```

See [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#function) for more information.